# Why can python lists hold more data than numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, out-of-memory

Sorry, I feel like this may be a basic question, but I did not find any "solutions" for this.

I am filling a `python` list with a lot of data, and finally want to convert it to a `numpy.array` for further processing.

However, when I call `numpy.asarray(my_list)`, I get an out of memory error. Why does that happen? Is it because `numpy.array` objects are stored in consecutive memory blocks, and there is not enough memory space for that?

How do I best treat such great data volumes then? I guess `numpy` is definitely the way to go, so I am a bit curious, that I can handle such volumes with simple `list` objects but not with my current `numpy` approach.

Again, repeating my most important question: How can I best handle data, which fits into `python` `lists` (so I guess overall it somehow still fits in my memory), but cannot be converted to a `numpy.array`?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that _both_ the list and the array have to be in memory at the same time. So that it doesn't fit doesn't mean the array is larger in memory than the list.

Comment: thats a good point, so your assuming my data is greater than half of my memory? and i guess one (the only) fix would be to directly go for numpy arrays, and use concat as append?

Comment: It'd help if you could say _how much_ data you have exactly, and what you want to do with it. As there are many different ways to deal with large data (most of them based on not having it all in memory at the same time).

Comment: i work with data similar to images, except its grids out of floats, i have around 1.000.000 samples of size 28x28.

Comment: So in the absolute perfect case of having it fit all into memory in one single array with no intermediate stuff at all, that's 28 x 28 x 1 million x 8 bytes for a float = 6.2GB. A Python list would take that at least that much, _plus_ references to each of the numbers to place in the list, so like 50% more at least.

Comment: It'd be easier to use some way to not have them all in memory at once, but it depends on what you need to do.

Comment: But you can use memmap with numpy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to work with arrays that are too large to fit into memory.

Comment: cool, thanks, that helped!

Comment: Also, you might have a broken list. If you made a list of lists and accidentally made all the sublists the same list instead of creating separate lists, then the data structure would take up very little memory, but also not work at all, and you might not notice without inspecting the contents manually.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the memory for a numpy array and never create a list in the first place.

memmap should not be neccessary as the original list fits in memory.